# How to create a Windows setup usb/iso but ignore specific hardware component or driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, setup, dism

A common issue I find online is people with the "DRIVER PNP WATCHDOG" bluescreen during the setup of windows from say a bootable ISO created with the Microsoft iso tool or with Rufus.
Whatever the cause may be, these machines boot fine with say Ubuntu Linux live usb.
So the problem is with microsoft blocking on some bad hardware.

Nonetheless, how do I get the windows setup to totally ignore a specific hardware piece that I know is the cause of issue?
In my case it's a Lenovo D330-10IGM that has a broken MMC internal harddrive, which cannot be unplugged. I've tried most of the usb writing tools and methods, but it won't pass the first loading screen of the initial windows setup, and then after some time it blue screens with the `driver pnp watchdog` error.

Or if I could see on which step of the windows setup it is crashing or stucking on, e.g. a verbose output of what the setup is loading? Then I could disable that step, but I don't know which step so I want to disable all access to drives on the machine, not at the OS level, but stop the setup from accessing the disk on the initial setup start-up level.

A WinPE loads fine by the way, as if it skips the broken disk correctly, but the full windows setup gets stuck on it.

**So  how to get the the windows setup from ignoring a broken hardware device at the lowest level possible, when that broken disk cannot be physically removed, nor disabled in the bios?**

**Update 1:** I see with dism, one can Remove-Driver's: `dism /Image:c:\temp\1Mount /Remove-Driver /Driver:sdbus.inf`
but it says

```
> Found 1 driver package(s) to remove. Removing 1 of 1 - sdbus.inf:
> Error - The specified driver cannot be removed. Removing a default
> driver package is not supported.
> 
> Error: 50
> 
> The request is not supported.
```

How to get around this error 50 from dism about not being able to remove default driver package.

---

Some examples of this issue from other people:


<sup>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/computer-will-boot-from-usb-to-linux-but-not-usb/ccb3b764-f5a7-44c0-9316-cff44819d620


https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-can-i-fix-driver-pnp-watchdog-error-if-windows/f9e6c237-f727-437e-8a31-21077000dd8d


https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/stop-code-driver-pnp-watchdog-error/507b9bbf-5555-48a7-aeef-930cb6ff8834


https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Notebooks/Ideapad-D330-10IGM-no-Emmc-deteced/m-p/5085990</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have gotten somewhere, I can get a USB to boot on this D330-10IGM that has a broken emmc internal disk. Took 2 days to get to this.

The problem was the windows setup cannot get past the fact that there is a broken disk. It can get past it in WINPE mode, but not normal mode.  Linux also gets past this issue.
So, how do you skip the broken emmc in a windows usb boot to setup or windows to go?

Well, you have to modify the iso or the boot image or usb that you are using.  There are lots of tools that can change the drivers of the images/iso/usb, e.g. dism++, NTLite, WSAT, DISM etc...

**and you must remove the drivers** for the broken internal mmc (an intel device of sorts), so that it doesn't access the disk when the Windows Setup/USB tries to start which then fails silently or bluescreen's eventually when it doesn't respond.

If you are using the Windows To Go usb for example, you can remove any of the driver files containing "sdbus" or "sdhost" in its name. Then the setup will skip those drivers, then it won't crash on the bluescreen "DRIVER PNP WATCHDOG", and it will boot up.

The windows to go installation has the files in plain sight so it can be removed easily. (some permissions need to be granted to delete them on some because of admin rights etc). Using some tools like DISM etc can work too to remove the drivers.